# Angular forms - remove validators after submit and reset

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have form in angular app.
When I hit submit button the `reset()` function is triggered on form.
After `reset()` all inputs are marked as they have errors.
How can I reset form and not have validation errors after this action or how can i clean this validation errors after.
I did try to `cleanValidators()` functions etc. nothing seems to work.

SUBMIT BUTON:

```
  <button mat-fab color="accent" type="submit">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    Register
  </button>
```

SUBMIT PART:

```
this.service.createRecord(record).subscribe(response => {
  setTimeout(() => this.form.reset(), 500);
});
```

I did try something like this (and it don't work):

```
this.formControls.forEach(control=>{
   this.form.get(control)?.clearValidators();
   this.form.get(control)?.setValidators([Validators.required]);
   this.form.get(control)?.updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

[UPDATE]

Ok, I'll show print screens. So this is my start point (after page is loaded):

[image]

then I'm clicking "Submit" button -> this triggers 'this.form.reset()`, after that it looks like this:

[image]

Nothing happens between, why this input is marked red?

This is how i declare form:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="Name" type="text" autocomplete="off" required/>
    <mat-error>{{'validation.requiredError' | translate}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<div>pristine: {{ visitForm.get("Name")?.pristine }}</div>
<div>touched: {{ visitForm.get("Name")?.touched }}</div>
<div>valid: {{ visitForm.get("Name")?.valid }}</div>
<div>disabled: {{ visitForm.get("Name")?.disabled}}</div>
```

```
this.form = new FormGroup({ 
    Autocomplete: new FormControl(), 
    Name: new FormControl('', Validators.required), 
    Surname: new FormControl('', Validators.required), 
});
```

Comment: You probably need to mark the form as `pristine`. After the `reset`,  try calling `this.form.markAsPristine()`.

Comment: There is a solution (using FormGroupDirective):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47225915/7389620

Answer (score 0):

Simple reset should be enough without having to go over each control individually (looks like you intend to clear them all).

```js
this.form.reset();
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validation-with-disable-and-tvbx3u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-edit%2Fperson-edit.component.ts

Comment: hello @Joosep.p .i have a question can you please help me with it , it seems you know you're way with angular and its a question about theme

Comment: click at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689563/angular-material-theme-the-text-overlaps-and-the-mat-icon-button-is-overlapped-w)

Comment: I can't see `resetForm`  function. I should mention it's `FormGroup` form.

Comment: Try this, it should explain quite well how the reactive forms work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validation-with-disable-and-tvbx3u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-edit%2Fperson-edit.component.ts