Input field shows "required" error immediately after clicking Create button, should show only when touched
I'm working on an Angular application where I'm creating a task using a form. The form has an input field that is marked as required. When I click the "Create" button, the input field immediately turns red because it's required, even if the field has not been touched yet.
I want the input field to only show the red border and the required error message after the user has interacted with the field (i.e., after it has been touched). How can I achieve this behavior in Angular?

The input field should only turn red and show the "required" error message after it has been touched by the user, not immediately after the form is submitted.
I couldn't reproduce the issue in a Stackblitz example, but I still hope someone might have an idea of what could be causing this behavior in my application.
Stackblitz Demo
task-form.component.ts
export class TaskFormComponent {
  protected readonly Object = Object;
  taskForm!: FormGroup;
  fromPopup = false;
  priorities = ['LOW', 'MEDIUM', 'URGENT'];
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    @Optional() private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TaskFormComponent>,
    @Optional()
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
    public data: { fromPopup: boolean; task: Task }
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fromPopup = !!this.data?.fromPopup;

    this.taskForm = this.fb.group({
      id: this.data?.task?.id,
      title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      priority: new FormControl('LOW', [Validators.required]),
    });

    if (this.data?.task) {
      this.taskForm.patchValue({
        id: this.data.task?.id,
        title: this.data.task.title,
      });
    }
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    // Create a task
    this.onReset();
  }

  public onReset() {
    this.taskForm.reset();
  }
}

task-form.component.html
<div mat-dialog-title>Create Task</div>

<mat-dialog-content>
  <form [formGroup]="taskForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        formControlName="title"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a title"
      />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Priority</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="priority">
        @for (priority of priorities; track priority) {
        <mat-option [value]="priority">{{ priority }} </mat-option>
        }
      </mat-select>
      @if (taskForm.get('priority')?.touched) {
      <mat-error>
        @switch (true) { @case (taskForm.get('priority')?.hasError('required'))
        { Priority is required } }
      </mat-error>
      }
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button
    (click)="onSubmit()"
    [disabled]="!taskForm.valid"
    mat-raised-button
    color="primary"
    type="submit"
  >
    Create
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>

ErrorStateMatcher (implemented in sign-up an not in create-task component):
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null
  ): boolean {
    return !!(form?.errors?.['mismatch'] && control?.touched);
  }
}


Based on your demo, the Create button is disabled unless all the form controls are valid. Thus, I not sure how you can submit the form without filling the controls.

Meanwhile, I suspect that you are implementing the ErrorStateMatcher and inject it globally. This could result the mentioned behavior. Maybe you can search it in your application and provide it in the question if found.

I mean the error occurs after I fill in the input fields and submit the form. I have implemented the ErrorStateMatcher only in my sign-up component and not in the create task component. However, I observed the following: the error only occurs with form controls that are required. When I remove the [Validators.required] validation, the mentioned error does not occur. I think that @if (taskForm.get('priority')?.touched) is not being reset upon form submission, which is why the error "Priority is required" is displayed.To be safe, I will include the ErrorStateMatcher in my question.

this.taskForm.markAsPristine() didn't work either when resetting the form .

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47225915/19648465
